# Nuxeo workflow engine VS dedicated workflow engine (like Activiti)

Tags: workflow, activiti, nuxeo

I use Nuxeo for content management purposes on a project.

I know I'll also need to support "workflow" scenarios, which I currently know very little about.
For example: I'll need to support a workflow scenario for approving a release of a software component.

Such an approval may be composed of several different stages, and in every stage I may need to trigger some kind of an automatic interaction with certain users of the system.

What may be considered some good/valid considerations for not "settling for" the workflow engine provided by Nuxeo, and using a dedicated engine such as Activiti or jBPM instead?

I know the question is very (perhaps too) broad, but still:

What could be some points to consider before I choose one over the other?

Are there other tools I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your question IS too broad. every workflow tool has its own cons and pros. why don't you list down all of your needs then compare each of the tools. mainly: Alfresco [Activiti](https://www.activiti.org/), [Camunda](https://camunda.org/), [jBPM](https://www.jbpm.org/) or [Nuxeo](https://www.nuxeo.com/)